# Probability confusion

Tags: python, math, probability

I was going though some practice [Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDsit.png).
The questions were:

(i) the probability that someone has both cold and a fever

(ii) the probability that someone who has a cough has a cold.

My answer for first is 0.307 but for second I am not sure how to find? any approach

Comment: Calling S = "has a cold", F = "has a fever" and T = "has a cough", how would you express the second probability formally?

Comment: @Stef It would be P(S|T) but T is true for two values with values 0.7525 and 0.505 so what would be the value of P(S|T)

Comment: Yes, that's P(S|T)! Now, do you know a theorem that can turn out very useful to calculate conditional probabilities?

Comment: @Stef is it Bayes' Theorem, so answer will be 0.7525 * 0.505 = 0.38 right?

Comment: Indeed Bayes' theorem can be useful. I did not click on your link so I have no idea what values you have, and can't tell you whether that's correct or not. Although I would expect three values to intervene in the application of Bayes' theorem: P(S|T) = ... * ... / ...